# How can I create an @supports statement for whether custom CSS properties are supported or not?

Tags: css

Basically, the title says it. By "custom CSS properties" I mean, for example `--main-color: black;`

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Simply like below. A random value assigned to a random custom property

```css
@supports not (--foo: bar) {
  body {
    background: red;
  }
}
```

The body background will turn red if your browser doesn't support custom properties

Comment: Are you doing that without --foo being declared anywhere? Or is --foo an already existing custom property?

Comment: @BrianHinkle you don't need any declaration, A random custom property like I am using is enough

Comment: I'm a little confused. Maybe it's just because I'm new to CSS. So how does this work if --foo isn't declared anywhere? I'm used to having to define the custom variable within an element selector's scope.

Comment: @BrianHinkle CSS variable never need to be declared. If you read this somewhere then it's wrong. variables in CSS aren't the same as in other languages like JS or C++. The browser will test the support of --foo which is a valid syntax of custom property. If the browser doesn't recognize it then there is no browser support for it